# Need to search for names, but have no Freetext index

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-catalog

I have a need to search names in our table, but we don't have a `FREETEXT` index setup.  This isn't an option anymore due to the large amount of data in the table.

Is there any alternatives that I can do?  Essentially I'd be looking at doing:

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE FREETEXT(FirstName, @firstname)
```

Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without full text indexes, then you'd maybe consider using

```
WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' + @firstname+ '%'
```

However it doesn't scale well (linearly, scan of all rows).

And you have a "large amount of data" which means you *really should* have full text indexes

Comment: This is what I was kind of hoping to steer clear off.  But, it looks like it's my only solution.